# Searching in Mongo by a date within at least one period

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a sample document in Mongo with sample fields:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "feeCode": "SAMPLE_FEE_CODE",
    "feeSuspensionPeriods": [
        {
            "startDate": "2021-01-01",
            "endDate": "2021-06-30"
        },
        {
            "startDate": "2022-01-01",
            "endDate": "2022-06-30"
        },
        {
            "startDate": "2023-01-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to write a query which will extract this document for me by feeCode and date. The date must contain at least one of the feeSuspensionPeriods.
For example:
When I ask for "SAMPLE_FEE_CODE" and "2021-01-01" parameters, it will return this document to me.
When I ask for "SAMPLE_FEE_CODE" and "2021-07-01" parameters, the document will not return it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$elemMatch` for this:

```
db.collection.find({
  feeCode: "SAMPLE_FEE_CODE",
  feeSuspensionPeriods: {
    $elemMatch: {
      startDate: {$lte: "2021-05-03"},
      endDate: {$gte: "2021-05-03"}
    }
  }
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hRIj5G7cCNS)

Answer (score 0):

you should try "elemMatch"

eg:

```
    _db._collectionName.find({
    feeCode: "SAMPLE_FEE_CODE",
  feeSuspensionPeriods: {
    $elemMatch: {
      startDate: {$lte: "yyyy-mm-dd"},
      endDate: {$gte: "yyyy-mm-dd"}
    }
  }
```